# Beautiful Soup code returning an "AttributeError"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm building a webscraper that returns the names of cafes written in the website like this: `<h2 class="venue-title" itemprop="name">Prior</h2>` However it is returning this error:

> "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
> [Finished in 0.699s]

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

soup_cafe_list = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
type(soup_cafe_list)

cafes = soup_cafe_list.findAll('h2', attrs_={"class":"venue-title"}).text
print(cafes)
```

I have tried a whole range of things to figure it out. I feel it has something to do with the findAll arg: `cafes = soup_cafe_list.findAll('h2', attrs_={"class":"venue-title"}).text` because when I run it as `cafes = soup_cafe_list.findAll('h2', class_="venue-title")` instead, it sort of works expect doesn't return the items cleaned of their html which I believe `.text` should do?

Another thing I'm noticing in the traceback is that it may be referring to a different directory for BS4? Could this have anything to do with it, I started off using Jupyter and now am on Atom, but may have incorrectly installed bs4:

> File "/Users/[xxxxxxxx]/Desktop/Coding/amvpscraper/webscraper.py", line 10, in 
> cafes = soup_cafe_list.findAll('h2', attrs_={"class":"venue-title"}).text
> File "/Users/[xxxxxxxx]/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2081, in **getattr**

Not sure if I am doing something else wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the return value of the findAll method is a list of elements and does not have a text attribute. Save the result in a list ( without .text method ) and replace attrs_ with attrs:

```
cafes = soup_cafe_list.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title"})
```

and then iterate through list and get the text. You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
cafes = [el.text for el in cafes]
```

**Edit**: List comprehensions simplify a for loop. You could also write:

```
res_list = []
for el in cafes:
    res_list.append(el.text)
```

Additionally, you may add some try-except clause or a check for a valid text field within the loop to catch possible elements without a text.

Output:

```
['Prior',
 'Rat the Cafe',
 'Ampersand Coffee and Food',
 'Umberto Espresso Bar',
 'Brother Alec',
 'Short Round',
 'Jerry Joy',
 'The Old Milk Bar',
 'Little Henri',
 'Northern Soul']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems to just be returning [ ] when I run the code now?

Comment: are you sure? I get this list: ['Prior', 'Rat the Cafe', 'Ampersand Coffee and Food', 'Umberto Espresso Bar', 'Brother Alec', 'Short Round', 'Jerry Joy', 'The Old Milk Bar', 'Little Henri', 'Northern Soul'] Edit: I renamed the attrs_ keyword in your code. This has to be attrs

Comment: Fantastic, that worked. Thank you. Just out of interest, can you explain how the second line of code `cafes = [el.text for el in cafes]` works?

Comment: @deadant88 added this to the answer. it is called a list comprehension and simplifies a for loop.